# Why is AJAX outputting the last echo statement even though the condition is false? PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I cannot figure out why the POST request is going through and the PHP code starts to be evaluated and everything goes as expected, except that my users see the "You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!" even though it should not be showing that as the if statement corresponding to that else is true, so why is it showing this output? It should be showing the success message further in, but is stuck showing this even though all the functions execute normally, etc..

AJAX Request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#purse').click(function() {
        $.ajax(
        {   
            type : "POST",
            url: "crimes-petty.php",
            data: {purse: 'true'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('div#outputContainer').html(JSON.parse(data));
            }

        });
    });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['purse'])) {
    if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
        if($char_gexp >= 400) {
            $crime_chance = 1;
        } else {
            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
            }
        }

        $crime_gexp = 2 * $gexp_multiplier;
        $crime_money = rand(20,100);
        $crime_jailchance = rand(1, 30);

        if($luckCategory == 1) {
            $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,75);
        } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
            $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,50);
        } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
            $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,35);
        }

        if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
            echo("You have failed to snatch any purses today!");
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
            if($crime_jailchance == 23) {
                echo("\nThe cops busted you for this one!");
                $char_jailtimestarted = time();
                addJailTime($db, $char_id, time() + $crime_jailchance, $char_jailtimestarted);
            }
        } else {
            echo("<div class='alert alert-success'>You have successfully ran off with " . $crime_money . " dollars after a hard day of snagging purses!</div>");
            successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
            increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
            calculatePower($db, $char_id);
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
            if($itemdrop_chance == 4 or $itemdrop_chance == 17 or $itemdrop_chance == 10 or $itemdrop_chance == 2 or $itemdrop_chance == 6) {
                $func_execute = findItemName($db, $purse_loottable[0]);
                $event_text = "You have picked up a $func_execute!";

                echo("<br>You have picked up a " . $func_execute . "!");

                event_add($char_id, $event_text);
                giveItem($db, $char_id, $purse_loottable[0], 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="outputContainer"></div>
<button type="button" name="purse" id="purse" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
```

All Code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container p-0" style="background-color: white; border-style: solid">

        <div class="my-auto">
        <h1 class="mb-0 text-center">Petty Crimes</h1>
        <h3 class="mb-0 text-center">Not the best, but it pays the bills</h3>
        <div class="text-center">
        <br>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#purse').click(function() {
                    $.ajax(
                    {   
                        type : "POST",
                        url: "crimes-petty.php",
                        data: {purse: 'true'},
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('div#outputContainer').html(data);
                        }

                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
        <?php
                if(isset($_POST['purse'])) {
                        if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
                            if($char_gexp >= 400) {
                                $crime_chance = 1;
                            } else {
                                if($luckCategory == 1) {
                                    $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
                                } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                                    $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
                                } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                                    $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
                                }
                            }

                            $crime_gexp = 2 * $gexp_multiplier;
                            $crime_money = rand(20,100);
                            $crime_jailchance = rand(1, 30);

                            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                                $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,75);
                            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                                $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,50);
                            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                                $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,35);
                            }

                            if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
                                echo("You have failed to snatch any purses today!");
                                addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
                                if($crime_jailchance == 23) {
                                    echo("\nThe cops busted you for this one!");
                                    $char_jailtimestarted = time();
                                    addJailTime($db, $char_id, time() + $crime_jailchance, $char_jailtimestarted);
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo("<div class='alert alert-success'>You have successfully ran off with " . $crime_money . " dollars after a hard day of snagging purses!</div>");
                                successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
                                increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
                                calculatePower($db, $char_id);
                                addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
                                if($itemdrop_chance == 4 or $itemdrop_chance == 17 or $itemdrop_chance == 10 or $itemdrop_chance == 2 or $itemdrop_chance == 6) {
                                    $func_execute = findItemName($db, $purse_loottable[0]);
                                    $event_text = "You have picked up a $func_execute!";

                                    echo("<br>You have picked up a " . $func_execute . "!");

                                    event_add($char_id, $event_text);
                                    giveItem($db, $char_id, $purse_loottable[0], 1);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
                        }
                    exit();
                 }
                 if(isset($_POST["checks"])) {
                    if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
                        if($char_gexp >= 800) {
                            $crime_chance = 1;
                        } else {
                            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                                $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
                            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                                $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
                            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                                $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
                            }
                        }

                        $crime_gexp = 4 * $gexp_multiplier;
                        $crime_money = rand(50,250);

                        if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
                            echo("You have failed to forge checks today!");
                            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
                        } else {
                            echo("You have successfully forged a few checks, they are worth about " . $crime_money . " dollars!");
                            successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
                            increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
                            calculatePower($db, $char_id);
                            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
                    }
                    exit();
                } 
                if(isset($_POST["cars"])) {
                    if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
                        if($char_gexp >= 1000) {
                            $crime_chance = 1;
                        } else {
                            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                                $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
                            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                                $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
                            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                                $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
                            }
                        }

                        $crime_gexp = 5 * $gexp_multiplier;
                        $crime_money = rand(120,300);

                        if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
                            echo("You have failed to sell any stolen cars!");
                            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
                        } else {
                            successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
                            increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
                            calculatePower($db, $char_id);
                            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
                            echo("<div class='alert alert-success'>You have successfully sold a few cars to the local chop shop for about " . $crime_money . " dollars!</div>");
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
                    }
                    exit();
                }

        ?>
            <div id="outputContainer"></div>
            <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Steal a few purses.
            <button type="submit" name="purse" id="purse" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
            <?php if($char_gexp >= 200) : ?>
                <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Forge checks.
                <button type="submit" name="checks" id="checks" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if($char_gexp >= 400) : ?>
                <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Steal cars.
                <button type="submit" name="cars" id="cars" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
            <?php endif ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$char_nextcrime`?

Comment: It's on a seperate file included at the top, but not shown in the code in the thread. It gets declared and assigned there with a value from my database, I've even tried doing that conditional outside of the code above and a 1 gets echoed, obviously meaning it is true. The odd part is, the code through the if statement will execute as if it was true, then it will go to the else statement there and output that echo.

Comment: Something must be changing `$nextcrime` before it gets to this code. PHP is not likely to get an `if` statement wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that it's executing both the `if` and `else` code? So you're seeing all the echoes?

Comment: What is `#purse`? Is it a submit button in a form? If it is, it will also cause the form to be submitted normally, which could be what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, it is executing BOTH the second if and else statement in the PHP code. The #purse is indeed a submit button, I'll edit the html in.

Comment: Make it `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Comment: What you're seeing is probably the output of `crimes-pretty.php` instead of `pretty.php`.

Comment: Woops, fixed the error in the code, in the question, but my issue with using a button over submit is that the user has to refresh to see any variable update and doesn't get any echos from AJAX. Is there a way that I can get this to work without changing it from a submit?

Comment: The AJAX `success` function is supposed to update the DOM.

Comment: I added something for AJAX success to update, but it doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: You're returning HTML, but `type: 'json'` means you're supposed to return JSON.

Comment: Aren't you seeing an error in the JavaScript console when it tries to parse the HTML as JSON? You do have the JavaScript console open when you're debugging JavaScript code, don't you?

Comment: Nothing is showing up on my console, on my end.

Comment: I am struggling when it comes to converting whatever comes through data to HTML, from JSON.

Comment: You're not returning JSON at all. Use `dataType: 'html'`

Comment: The problem is if I do dataType: 'html', it returns the whole page over itself in a very weird way, It's like it is shoving the whole page and spitting it out via AJAX.

Comment: It will display whatever `crimes-pretty.php` returns. Make sure that when `$_POST['crime']` is set that it doesn't print anything except what you've shown above.

Comment: Try putting `exit();` at the end of the `if(isset($_POST['crime']))` block, if you have other code after this that returns other HTML.

Comment: That definitely works to a certain extent, for some reason now just the headings and success message are getting sent back through instead of the whole page

Comment: I edited my post to show *almost* all the code for the current page all in one go to make it easier to follow.

Comment: Also to be noted, it seems I cannot get the results I want without including <form> along with the AJAX request, the information doesn't update unless I refresh, but I heard AJAX was my solution to this..

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all the code that processes AJAX requests to the beginning, so that you don't print any other HTML before you do that.

It could be easier to split this into two separate scripts, one that displays the regular page, and another that processes AJAX requests.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['purse'])) {
    if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
        if($char_gexp >= 400) {
            $crime_chance = 1;
        } else {
            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
            }
        }

        $crime_gexp = 2 * $gexp_multiplier;
        $crime_money = rand(20,100);
        $crime_jailchance = rand(1, 30);

        if($luckCategory == 1) {
            $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,75);
        } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
            $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,50);
        } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
            $itemdrop_chance = rand(1,35);
        }

        if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
            echo("You have failed to snatch any purses today!");
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
            if($crime_jailchance == 23) {
                echo("\nThe cops busted you for this one!");
                $char_jailtimestarted = time();
                addJailTime($db, $char_id, time() + $crime_jailchance, $char_jailtimestarted);
            }
        } else {
            echo("<div class='alert alert-success'>You have successfully ran off with " . $crime_money . " dollars after a hard day of snagging purses!</div>");
            successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
            increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
            calculatePower($db, $char_id);
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
            if($itemdrop_chance == 4 or $itemdrop_chance == 17 or $itemdrop_chance == 10 or $itemdrop_chance == 2 or $itemdrop_chance == 6) {
                $func_execute = findItemName($db, $purse_loottable[0]);
                $event_text = "You have picked up a $func_execute!";

                echo("<br>You have picked up a " . $func_execute . "!");

                event_add($char_id, $event_text);
                giveItem($db, $char_id, $purse_loottable[0], 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
    }
    exit();
}
if(isset($_POST["checks"])) {
    if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
        if($char_gexp >= 800) {
            $crime_chance = 1;
        } else {
            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
            }
        }

        $crime_gexp = 4 * $gexp_multiplier;
        $crime_money = rand(50,250);

        if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
            echo("You have failed to forge checks today!");
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
        } else {
            echo("You have successfully forged a few checks, they are worth about " . $crime_money . " dollars!");
            successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
            increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
            calculatePower($db, $char_id);
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
        }
    } else {
        echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
    }
    exit();
} 
if(isset($_POST["cars"])) {
    if($char_nextcrime <= time()) {
        if($char_gexp >= 1000) {
            $crime_chance = 1;
        } else {
            if($luckCategory == 1) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,9);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 2) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,16);
            } elseif($luckCategory == 3) {
                $crime_chance = rand(1,25);
            }
        }

        $crime_gexp = 5 * $gexp_multiplier;
        $crime_money = rand(120,300);

        if($crime_chance == 2 or $crime_chance == 6 or $crime_chance == 7 or $crime_chance == 4) {
            echo("You have failed to sell any stolen cars!");
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
        } else {
            successfulCrime($db, $char_id, $char_money, $crime_money, $totalCrimes, $char_gexp, $crime_gexp);
            increaseStatsForCrimes($db, $char_id, "Petty", $luckCategory);
            calculatePower($db, $char_id);
            addCrimeTime($db, $char_id, 60);
            echo("<div class='alert alert-success'>You have successfully sold a few cars to the local chop shop for about " . $crime_money . " dollars!</div>");
        }
    } else {
        echo("<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must wait 60 seconds between crimes!</div>");
    }
    exit();
}

?>

<body>
<div class="container p-0" style="background-color: white; border-style: solid">

    <div class="my-auto">
    <h1 class="mb-0 text-center">Petty Crimes</h1>
    <h3 class="mb-0 text-center">Not the best, but it pays the bills</h3>
    <div class="text-center">
    <br>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#purse').click(function() {
                    $.ajax(
                        {   
                        type : "POST",
                                url: "crimes-petty.php",
                                data: {purse: 'true'},
                                dataType: 'html',
                                success: function(data) {
                                $('div#outputContainer').html(data);
                            }

                        });
                });
        });

</script>
<div id="outputContainer"></div>
    <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Steal a few purses.
    <button type="submit" name="purse" id="purse" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
    <?php if($char_gexp >= 200) : ?>
    <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Forge checks.
    <button type="submit" name="checks" id="checks" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if($char_gexp >= 400) : ?>
    <div class="subheading mb-5 text-center"><br>Steal cars.
    <button type="submit" name="cars" id="cars" class="btn btn-dark center-block">Submit</button>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That does work nicely and I thank you greatly for putting up with me, I do have one question though. The whole reason I looked into AJAX for my project is because I heard it can update everything without a page refresh, but my sidebar values that get affected by all the database queries done do not change without a refresh, any advice?

Comment: That's why it's usually better to return JSON than HTML. You can return all the data you want to update, but then you have to write JavaScript code that puts everything in the appropriate place in the DOM.

Comment: You could also combine it. You can return a JSON object where the values are HTML strings, e.g. `echo json_encode(['container' => $containerHTML, 'sidebar' => $sidebarHTML]);`. Then you can do `$("#outputContainer").html(result.container); $("sidebar").html(result.sidebar);`